# Brighten only dark areas of image in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to process images and I would like to brighten the dark areas of my image. I tried Histogram Equalization, however as there are also some bright areas in the image, the result is not satisfying. This is why I am looking for a way to brighten **only the dark areas** of the image.

As an example, Input image is on the left and the expected result is on the right, the hair and face of the girl are brightened

[image: Input Image]
[image: Brightened Image]

ImageMagick seems to offer some possibilities to achieve this, however, I would like to do it using python

Comment: What **ImageMagick** commands did you have success with, please?

Comment: I saw some interesting results [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=36703) but I am open to propositions

Comment: You are likely to get better answers if you provide images that are actually representative of those you want to process rather than using some random, 3 year old images which may be of a different quality, type and content...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to avoid colour distortions, you could:

- convert to HSV colourspace,
- split the channels,
- bump up the V (Value) channel
- recombine the channels
- save

That might go something like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open the image
im = Image.open('hEHxh.jpg')

# Convert to HSV colourspace and split channels for ease of separate processing
H, S, V = im.convert('HSV').split()

# Increase the brightness, or Value channel
# Change 30 to 50 for bigger effect, or 10 for smaller effect
newV = V.point(lambda i: i + int(30*(255-i)/255))

# Recombine channels and convert back to RGB
res = Image.merge(mode="HSV", bands=(H,S,newV)).convert('RGB')

res.save('result.jpg')
```

[image]

Essentially, I am changing the brightness from the black mapping to the green mapping:

[image]

---

Reminder to forgetful self... *"you made the plot like this, Mark"*:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some straight-line data
xdata = np.arange(0,256)
# And the new mapping
ydata = xdata + 30*(255-xdata)/255

# Plot
plt.plot(xdata,xdata,'.k')
plt.plot(xdata,ydata,'g^')
plt.title('Adjustment of V')
plt.xlabel('Input V')
plt.ylabel('Output V')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Very interesting, is there an advantage using the V from HSV versus using the Y from YUV or YCrCb for instance?

Comment: I don't know - try it for your images You have the code - plug in the other modes and their respective channel names. It shouldn't take a minute. PIL supports YCbCr and Lab modes, so you could try changing `Y` and `L`...

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do that in Imagemagick and Python/OpenCV. Threshold the L channel of LAB colorspace using triangle method. Then brighten the whole image. Then merge the original and brightened image using the threshold as a mask.

**Imagemagick:**

```
magick girl_on_chair.jpg \
\( -clone 0 -colorspace LAB -channel 0 -separate +channel \
-auto-threshold triangle -negate +write thresh.png \) \
\( -clone 0 -evaluate multiply 4 \) \
+swap -compose over -composite \
girl_on_chair_processed.jpg
```

Threshold:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**Python/OpenCV:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("girl_on_chair.jpg")

# convert to LAB and extract L  channel
LAB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
L = LAB[:,:,0]

# threshold L channel with triangle method
value, thresh = cv2.threshold(L, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_TRIANGLE)
print(value)

# threshold with adjusted value
value = value + 10
thresh = cv2.threshold(L, value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# invert threshold and make 3 channels
thresh = 255 - thresh
thresh = cv2.merge([thresh, thresh, thresh])

gain = 3
blue = cv2.multiply(img[:,:,0], gain)
green = cv2.multiply(img[:,:,1], gain)
red = cv2.multiply(img[:,:,2], gain)
img_bright = cv2.merge([blue, green, red])

# blend original and brightened using thresh as mask
result = np.where(thresh==255, img_bright, img)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('girl_on_chair_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('girl_on_chair_brighten.jpg', result)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('L', L)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('img_bright', img_bright)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I always get a great deal from your posts +1. Where can I get info on triangle threshold?

Comment: @JeruLuke.  See my Imagemagick script, trianglethresh, for examples and description at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/trianglethresh/index.php also see https://forum.image.sc/t/understanding-imagej-implementation-of-the-triangle-algorithm-for-threshold/752 and search Google for other examples

Answer (score 3):

An alternate way to do this in Imagemagick is to use -fx to threshold and increase brightness using the L channel of LAB or the Y channel of YCbCr or the V channel of HSV by adding a constant value where that channel is less than some threshold.

*(Note: In -fx, images such as`u` vary from 0 to 1 in range.)*

```
magick girl_on_chair.jpg \
-colorspace LAB -separate \
\( -clone 0 -fx "u<0.15?u+0.15:u" \) \
-swap 0,3 +delete \
-set colorspace LAB -combine -colorspace sRGB \
girl_on_chair_proc2.jpg

magick girl_on_chair.jpg \
-colorspace YCBCR -separate \
\( -clone 0 -fx "u<0.15?u+0.15:u" \) \
-swap 0,3 +delete \
-set colorspace YCBCR -combine -colorspace sRGB \
girl_on_chair_proc3.jpg

magick girl_on_chair.jpg \
-colorspace HSV -separate \
\( -clone 2 -fx "u<0.15?u+0.15:u" \) \
+swap +delete \
-set colorspace HSV -combine -colorspace sRGB \
girl_on_chair_proc4.jpg
```

LAB Result:

[image]

YCbCr Result:

[image]

HSV Result:

[image]

Similar processing can be done using Python/OpenCV as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("girl_on_chair.jpg")

# convert to LAB and extract L  channel
LAB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
L,A,B = cv2.split(LAB)

# process L channel
L_proc = np.where(L<40, cv2.add(L,40), L)

# recombine L_proc with A and B
LAB_new = cv2.merge([L_proc, A, B])

# convert back to BGR
result = cv2.cvtColor(LAB_new, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('girl_on_chair_brighten2.jpg', result)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('L', L)
cv2.imshow('L_proc', L_proc)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Most answers are using a different color space, is there any reason you chose LAB over another one?

Comment: No, I showed an answer where I use 3 different color spaces and the results were similar. Just get a channel that represents luminance/brightness etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can accomplish that with just the `cv2` module:

```
import cv2

def lighten(img, value=30):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    v = hsv[..., 2]
    v[:] = cv2.add(v, value)
    return cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 175, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] == 0
img[mask] = lighten(img)[mask]
cv2.imshow("result", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Input Image and Output Image:

[image] [image]

Comment: Most answers are using a different color space, is there any reason you chose HSV over another one?

Comment: @arnino HSV stands for Hue, Saturation, Value, where Value refers to the relative lightness or darkness of a color. So that's why I'm using it to lighten the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the [`tonelut`](https://www.libvips.org/API/current/libvips-create.html#vips-tonelut) operation in [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/). It should be high quality, and pretty quick.

It brightens L* in CIELAB. This is a good choice for this sort of operation, since L* divides brightness into 100 steps of just visible difference. 20%, 50% and 80% of the L* range are useful rule of thumb  positions for the shadows, midtones and highlights.

It works like this:

- The image is converted to LABS colourspace. This is CIELAB, but represented as signed short, so 0-32767 for L* and +/- 32767 for a* and b*
- It finds the histogram of the L* (zero) band, and uses that to determine the 1% and 99% points of this image
- These are then passed to `tonelut` to set black and white for the generated tone adjustment function. The user can adjust the shadow, midtone and highlight boosts via command-line arguments
- `tonelut` uses a set of splines to generate a smooth and monotonic tone remapping function
- L* is mapped through the tone adjustment curve
- Finally, it converts back to the original colourspace and writes

Code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import pyvips

input_filename = sys.argv[1]
output_filename = sys.argv[2]
shadow_boost = float(sys.argv[3])
midtone_boost = float(sys.argv[4])
highlight_boost = float(sys.argv[5])

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])

# we work in LABS format, a 16-bit version of LAB, with 0 - 32767 for L*, and
# +/- 32767 for a* and b* +/- 128
original_interpretation = image.interpretation
image = image.colourspace("labs")

# find the histogram of L* and use it to pick the 1% and 99% points as black
# and white
hist = image[0].hist_find();
norm = hist.hist_cum().hist_norm()  # normalised cumulative histogram
black = (norm > norm.width * 0.01).profile()[1].avg()
white = (norm > norm.width * 0.99).profile()[1].avg()

# tonelut wants percentages of 0-32767
black = 100.0 * black / 32767.0
white = 100.0 * white / 32767.0

# make a tone-mapping function using those black and white points
tone = pyvips.Image \
    .tonelut(Lb=black, Lw=white, \
        S=shadow_boost, M=midtone_boost, H=highlight_boost)

# remap L* of the image
image = (image[0].maplut(tone)).bandjoin(image[1:])

# back to the original interpretation, and save
image = image.colourspace(original_interpretation)

image.write_to_file(output_filename)
```

I can run it like this:

```
$ ./tone.py ~/pics/girl.jpg x.jpg +10 +10 0
```

That's boosting the midtones as well, since that's where the skin falls. Here's a before and after:

[image: before and after]

We'd be able to pull more out of a better-quality test image.